# template class for specific data type

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

(the code is simlified for the sake of simplicity)
I want to create a Test class with template E A and also a Test class with only E template. When I've done this and tried to compile my code, I got these errors:

> error C2976: 'Test': too few template arguments
>
> note: see declaration of 'Test'
>
> error C2244: 'Test::Output': unable to match function definition to an
>   existing declaration
>
> error C2662: 'void Test::Output(void)': cannot convert 'this'
>   pointer from 'Test' to 'Test &'
>
> error C2514: 'Test': class has no constructors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template <typename E, typename A>
class Test
{
public:
    Test(E *e = nullptr, A *a = nullptr) : a(e), b(a) {}
    void Output();

private:
    E * a;
    A *b;
};
template <typename E, typename A>
void Test<E, A>::Output()
{
    std::cout << " " << *a << " " << *b;
}

template <typename E>
class Test
{
public:
    Test(E *e = nullptr, std::string *a = nullptr) : a(e), b(a) {}
    void Output();

private:
    E * a;
    std::string *b;
};

template<typename E>
void Test<E>::Output()
{
    std::cout << *a << *b;
}
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    std::string str = "hi";

    Test<int> t(&a, &str);
    t.Output();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class templates can't be overloaded (function templates can), but only specialized. If you want [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization), it should be

```
template <typename E>
class Test<E, E>
{
    ...
};
```

and

```
template<typename E>
void Test<E, E>::Output()
{
    ...
}
```

And when use it, you should always specify two template arguments as the primary template being declared. i.e.

```
Test<int, int> t(&a, &str); // the partial specialization will be used
```

**EDIT**

> Can I set the second template as a specific data type (such as `std::string`)? and use `Test` like `Test<int, std::string>`

Yes. e.g.

```
template <typename E>
class Test<E, std::string>
{
    ...
};
```

and

```
template<typename E>
void Test<E, std::string>::Output()
{
    ...
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LnKWXhVK4KaKDP8T)

Comment: Can I set the second template as a specific data type (such as std::string)? and use Test like Test<int, std::string>

Comment: Yes, I know this can be done this way. But what if I want to define a class template Test with two template arguments like template <typename E, typename A> and also specifically define methods for Test class with A is of std::string type?

Comment: @CharlieLee I didn't get your question exactly. You meant don't partial specialize class template but only partial specialize member function?

Comment: I mean can I have a class template: e.g. Test<E, A>  (where E and A are both templates) but at the meantime define specific functions when A is std::string

Comment: @CharlieLee You have to do some kind of specialization, class specialization (like my answer showed) or member function specialization.

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work out, could you post your full code in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not "overload" a class template by declaring `template typename E> class Test`. Class `Test` must be take two template parameters.

The solution here would be to declare a completely different template class or make second template parameter optional and write a template specialization:

```
class Dummy;
template <typename E, typename A = Dummy>
class Test
…

template <typename E>
class Test<E, Dummy>
```

So syntax `Test<int> t(&a, &str);` will still work.